# Deactivate default styles in non-webkit browsers

Tags: css, cross-browser

I tried to customise form inputs in my web-app, and to do this I had to clear default browser styles with

```
-webkit-appearance: none
```

So in Chrome and Safari I have nice looking checkboxes, radio etc. But in FF and Opera looks like both styles are active, mine and the browser's. Is there way to deactivate default styles for FF, IE and Opera?

UPDATE:
I've already tried `-o-appearance: none` and `-moz-appearance: none`, it gives no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox and IE don't (yet) support the appearance property.

However, you can easily customize inputs such as `checkboxes` and `radio buttons` with pure css.

The implementation involves hiding the input and using the label (with the `before` pseudo element for the custom styles) to trigger the input

See this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/EwfwQ/2/) for cross-browser customized inputs.